# How to synchronize button text of buttons under different tab in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a button. The component is created in its parent component twice (under different tabs areas, same page). If the user clicks the button, the button text will change. I hope the button texts are always the same whatever button is clicked and changed.
I have tried updating the state of the course component in click functions, so the text of the button can be changed based on the state condition. It doesn’t work. I guess the click function just updates the state of a component of one tab rather than another tab. Any way to implement the synchronization? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean another browser tab? Then the only way to sync them is to have a server backend that keeps track of the button state and propagates them to all clients.

Comment: @kwsp Thanks for reminding me! I mean the same page. Just different area

Comment: Use the same state variable for both buttons to store the button text